# I want to ignore default preferences set by the user in react-native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, mobile-development

I am making an app in react-native but wherever I'm using text I want that to be constant as I set it.
For e.g - I don't want my text to be scaled if the user has increased the default font size of his device. In one word - I just want to all the default user preferences/settings on his device.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use allowFontScaling prop

```
<Text allowFontScaling={false} />
```

The [doc](https://reactnative.dev/docs/text#allowfontscaling)

**Edit:**

I don't know any way to configure the setting for the whole app. The best I could come up with is creating your own Text component and changing the Text import statement.

```
export function MyText(props) {
    return <Text {...props} allowFontScaling={false} />
}
```

```js
import { Text } from "react-native" // change this line to
import { MyText as Text } from "../location/to/your/component"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. But this has to be applied all over the project again and again, right? Is there some package or something which does this exact thing only after writing once or twice? BTW, this was of great help thanks!

Comment: @VenomKage I'm glad you found it helpful. Check the edited answer!

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is an amazing method!